# Can't connect to mongodb remotely

Tags: mongodb

I have a server on Digital Ocean running a MongoDB instance, if I `ssh` into the server, I can connect to the Mongo Shell with no problem. When I try to connect on my own machine, with PyMongo, it also connects with no problem.

The problem is when I try to connect from my machine via Mongo Shell, then I get

```
MongoDB shell version v3.6.3
connecting to: mongodb://<server_ip>:4131/?replicaSet=mongodb%3A
2018-06-26T11:50:05.799-0300 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: '/<server_ip>:4131' in 'mongodb://<server_ip>:4131/?replicaSet=mongodb%3A' appears to be a unix socket, but does not end in '.sock' :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:251:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

So as some may have noticed, I did change the port to `4131`, and yes, I pass this information on my connection string.

I have done a lot of research and already discarded some things:

- No, there's no .lock file, and I have made sure to run `mongod --repair` just to be sure.
- My `/etc/mongod.conf` has external ips enabled, (ie.: `bindIp: 0.0.0.0`)

Extra information:

- There is a `/tmp/mongodb-4131.sock` file, which should be the socket mongo shell is looking for, right?
- I looked up before changing the ports and made sure nothing was using `4131`
- Firewall is disabled (just to make sure that's not the problem)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Just in case someone is having the same problem, I managed to solve the problem by removing `"mongodb://"` from my `--host` argument, basically I just use `--host "<server_ip>"` and it works